# What is the highest possible score in Ticket To Ride: Europe?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe, puzzles

During lockdown, my partner and I have gotten quite good at Ticket To Ride: Europe (TTRE). We have have been wondering what the theoretical maximum score possible in TTRE is? Assuming perfect draws and opponents not being relevant (basically single player)

Comment: Perfect draws aren't at all relevant, are they? Because you can just draw the entire train card deck as you want/need.

Comment: Perfect draws of destination cards matter.

Comment: In the Europe version you should be able to increase the score by having the second player build a few routes and use you station to pull in a few extra tickets.

Comment: @GendoIkari "perfect draws" surely referring to destination cards.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, but having scored 189 in a game a couple of weeks ago, I couldn't believe 195 is the max score.

Edinburgh - Athína gets 21 points with 20 carriages, so I decided to explore possibilities from that route.

I set up the board and checked for the best routes to add.
I came up with this setup:

### Points for the routes

- **Edinburgh - Athína ----------> 21 points**
- Edinburgh - Paris ---------------> 7 points
- Paris - Zágráb ------------------> 7 points
- Paris - Wien ---------------------> 8 points
- London - Wien ----------------> 10 points
- London - Berlin -----------------> 7 points
- Berlin - Bucuresti --------------> 8 points
- Berlin - Moskva ---------------> 12 points
- Berlin - Roma -------------------> 9 points
- Roma - Smyrna ----------------> 8 points
- Zágráb - Brindisi ---------------> 6 points
- Zürich - Brindisi ----------------> 6 points
- Zürich - Budapest -------------> 6 points
- Amsterdam - Wilno ----------> 12 points
- Athína - Wilno ----------------> 11 points
- Essen - Kyïv ------------------> 10 points
- Venezia - Constantinople ---> 10 points
- Frankfurt - Smolensk --------> 13 points

This makes a total of 150 for the shorter routes and 21 for the long one (=**171**)

### European Express

Track length 43+2 (**10 points for longest route/European Express**)

### Points for the carriages:

- Edinburgh - London_____________________4 carriages_____7 points
- London - Amsterdam____________________2 carriages_____2 points
- Amsterdam - Essen_____________________3 carriages_____4 points
- Essen - Berlin_________________________2 carriages_____2 points
- Berlin - Wien__________________________3 carriages_____4 points
- Wien - Budapest_______________________1 carriage______1 point
- Budapest - Zágráb______________________2 carriages_____2 points
- Zágráb - Venezia_______________________2 carriages_____2 points
- Venezia - Zürich________________________2 carriages_____2 points
- Venezia - Roma________________________2 carriages_____2 points
- Roma - Brindisi________________________2 carriages_____2 points
- Brindisi - Athína________________________4 carriages_____7 points
- Athína - Smyrna_______________________2 carriages_____2 points
- Smyrna - Constantinople________________2 carriages_____2 points
- Constantinople - Bucuresti_______________3 carriages_____4 points
- Bucuresti - Kyïv________________________4 carriages_____7 points
- Kyïv - Smolensk________________________3 carriages_____4 points
- Smolensk - Moskva_____________________2 carriages_____2 points

Points for the carriages is **58** in total (this score is not that high, so there might still be room for a few dozen points of improvement.)

### Stations:

- Wilno (from Kyïv or Smolensk)
- Frankfurt (from Amsterdam, Essen or Berlin)
- Paris (from Zürich or Frankfurt)

**171+10+58=239 points.**

[image: TTRE 239]

Comment: Replacing a 4-carriage-route with a station and two stations with the freed carriages, means you free up a station, but probably lose the longest route. The spare station can be used for a new destination (Angora (5) / København (5) / Petrograd (6) / Warszawa (6) / Pamplona (7) / Palermo (8) / Brest (8) / Marseille (8) / **Sofia (5+5) / Riga (10)** ) or saved for 4 points. This makes the new total: 239 - 7 + 2 +2 + 10 = **246** if you have the longest route with 34 carriages. If you don't have the longest route, you'll have 236 points.

Comment: If you can swap some routes to free enough carriages to get Barcelona - Munchen, Barcelona - Bruxelles and Bruxelles - Danzic       or       Brest - Venezia, Brest - Marseille and Marseille - Essen, you might improve your score.

Comment: What about the destination cards? You should assume that you get longest route: this is largest possible score, and it's possible to get longest route.

Comment: Acccumulation, I don't understand your question. Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: Maybe I just missed them, but I didn't see where you included points for destination cards.

Comment: At "Points for the routes" are the points for the destination cards.

Answer (score 2):

So myself and my daughter had a go at this and if you don't use stations i.e.
you get 12 points for them, we got to 172 points going from Roma to Palermo and along the longest routes through Bucaresti,  Budapest and Kyiv, then Petrograd to Stockholm. This gave a route of 44 carriages,  so assumes longest route.
It completes one long route and six short ones.
Using stations opens up a bit of a can of worms and it would be an unknown as to whether there'd be two adjacent routes to use. However,  assuming only *one* attached route off your own and using all three stations, three other double figure routes are possible. So lose 12 for stations but gain 35. Total score 195. 
Routes completed along the long route were:

- Palermo to Moscow
- Kyiv to Petrograd
- Stockholm to Wien
- Roma to Smyrna
- Budapest to Sofia
- Palermo to Constantinople
- Sofia to Smyrna

Additional routes using stations all scored ten or more.

Comment: I’m confused as to why it matters if there are multiple routes claimed next to a station.   The station can only use one of these routes anyway.  A station can’t use one route for one ticket and then use a different route for another.

Comment: I believe that the poster is talking about only using a station to bridge a 'gap' of one route. Its kinda hard to explain, but I'll try: Imagine they had a route that ended with Wien to Warsawa, the poster would consider routes using 1 station to get from Warsawa to Wilno, but not a second station to use two routes to get to Petrograd.

Comment: @NeilTarrant absolutely.  I think it maximises points to use one station per route, but happy to be proven wrong if there are some smarter moves.

Answer (score 1):

Link to the picture of the route I thought of:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaLzd.png

- 45 trains + 3 trainstations
- Points for traincarriage:  52x
- Mountain routes: 4x
- Locomotives needed: 4x
- 21 tickets but no bonus for European Express
- Green cirkels on the map are the trainstations*

*** 1: Palermo-Moskva (20)

2: Frankfurt-Smolensk (13)

3: Amsterdam-Wilno (12)

4: Berlin-Moskva (12)

5: Athina-Wilno (11)

6: Essen-Kyiv (10)

7: Venizia-Constantinople (10)

8: London-Wien (10)

9: Berlin-Roma (9)

10: Roma-Smyrna (8)

11: Marseille-Essen (8)

*** 12: Palermo-Constantinople (8)

13: Paris-Wien (8)

14: Brest-Venezia (8)

15: Berlin-Bucuresti (8)

16: Brest-Marseille (7)

17: Paris-Zagreb (7)

18: London-Berlin (7)

19: Zurich-Budapest (6)

20: Sofia-Smyrna (5)

21: Budapest-Sofia (5)

---------------------------------- +

192 points + 52 points = 244 points

Alternative longest routes
*** Palermo-Moskva (20)     Palermo-Constantinople (8)  = 28 points
*** Edinburgh-Athina (21)       Edinburgh-Paris (7)     = 28 points
*** Brest-Petrograd (20)        Kyiv-Petrograd (6)      = 26 points

Comment: I found 2 more points if you swap out Sofia - Bucaresti for Roma - Brindisi. The two Sofia tickets are worth 5 points each. The two Brindisi tickets are worth 6 points each.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself and came out with a very similar solution to [Etiën Alssema](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/35311/eti%C3%ABn-alssema)'s answer. It eeks out a few extra points. It scores 248 without counting the longest track.

- There is a continuous track 33 pieces long from Brest to Sofia.
- Train stations borrow red's tracks:

  - Budapest - Kyïv - Smolensk
  - Palermo - Roma

[image: 248 points]

| Total | 248 |
| --- | --- |
| Built tracks | 52 |
| Remaining train stations | 0 |
| Palermo - Moskva | 20 |
| Frankfurt - Smolensk | 13 |
| Amsterdam - Wilno | 12 |
| Berlin - Moskva | 12 |
| Athína - Wilno | 11 |
| Essen - Kyïv | 10 |
| London - Wien | 10 |
| Venezia - Constantinople | 10 |
| Berlin - Roma | 9 |
| Brest - Venezia | 8 |
| Marseille - Essen | 8 |
| Palermo - Constantinople | 8 |
| Paris - Wien | 8 |
| Roma - Smyrna | 8 |
| Brest - Marseille | 7 |
| London - Berlin | 7 |
| Paris - Zágráb | 7 |
| Zágráb - Brindisi | 6 |
| Zürich - Brindisi | 6 |
| Zürich - Budapest | 6 |
| Budapest - Sofia | 5 |
| Sofia - Smyrna | 5 |

Answer (score -1):

I am playing the pc version. I just scored a whopping 347 to AI 94.  Need to connect Angora to Madrid via Athens, Rome, and Marseille; Marseille to London via Paris and Dieppe; and Rome to Wien any path through the Alps.  From Wein, spurs to Bucurest, Berlin, and Frankfurt.  Use Stations where possible to ride on opponent's train.  I played early routes that blocked and confused AI.  Once I completed the first three main routes between Ankara, Madrid, and London, I just kept drawing more ticket, automatically completing 2 to 3 each draw for a total of 28 completed tickets and no incompletes.  AI completed only 2 tickets.

Comment: It looks like the PC version has more routes than the physical board game. None of the tickets you mention are in the boardgame, although they seem perfectly valid. It certainly adds replayability, though!

Comment: @Hand-E-Food maybe it is from the 1912 expansion?

Answer (score -1):

Not the theoretical max, but I've got 264 points. (Really inefficient)
Though I might've misinterpreted the rules. I'm assuming that for each separate mission I can take a different path with my stations. (Still just one per station don't worry.)

Train chains (NOT MISSION RELATED)

```
BREST-PARIS-FRANKFURT-BERLIN-ESSEN
     4 +   4 +       4 +    2 =   14
LONDON-AMSTERDAM-BRUXELLES
      2 +       1             =   3
PETROGRAD-WILNO-KYIV-WARZAWA
         7 +   2 +  7         =   16       
ANGORA-SMYRNA-ATHINA-SOFIA-BUCURESTI
     4 +    2  +   4 +   2    =   12
ZURICH-VENEZIA-ROMA      
       2  +   2               =   4
VENEZIA-ZAGREB-BUDAPEST-WIEN
      2  +   2 +       1.     =   5  
                                  54
```

Stations: PARIS, KYIV, BERLIN

Main mission:

```
BREST - PETROGRAD   20
BERLIN - ROMA  9
ROMA - SMYRNA 8
37
ZURICH - BUDAPEST 6
SOFIA - SMYRNA 5
LONDON - WIEN 10
21
ATHINA - ANGORA 5
ATHINA - WILNO 11
BREST - VENEZIA 8
24
PARIS - ZAGREB 7
BREST - MARSEILLE 7
ESSEN - KYIV 10
24
BERLIN - BUCHAREST 8
MARSEILLE - ESSEN 8
BERLIN - MOSKVA 12
28
BRUXELLES - DANZIG 9
FRANKFURT - SMOLENSK 13
BUDAPEST - SOFIA 5
27
LONDON - BERLIN 7
AMSTERDAM - WILNO 12
PARIS - WIEN 8
27
KYIV -PETROGRAD 6
WARZAWA - SMOLENSK 6
12
200
```

LONGEST TRAIN 10

264.

I believe in 300+.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying but I believe this means you are playing incorrectly "I'm assuming that for each separate mission I can take a different path with my stations."; quoting from the official rules "If a player uses the same Station to help connect cities on several different Tickets, he must use the same route into the city with the Station for all of those Tickets."